# Laravel validating an input array

Tags: arrays, validation, laravel

I'm new to this laravel. I have this codes from another developer. Now the client want to update the order form products to put in into checkbox the list of products.

Here how product blade looks like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="{{ $pp->name }}"> {{ $pp->name }}<br />
```

and below is the controller: I get "ARRAY" printed as result. Can anyone help me how to get the product array values from checkbox.

```
function post_sendorder(){

$rules = array(
    'name' => 'required|min:2',
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'phone' => 'required|alpha_dash',
    'message' => 'required|min:5',
'product' => 'required'
);

$v = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
$v = $v->fails() ? $v : true;

if($v !== true) return Redirect::to_route('prods')->with_errors($v->errors)->with_input()->with('show_order',true);

Message::send(function($message){
        $message->to('mail@gmail.com');         
        $message->from(Input::get('email'), Input::get('name'));
        $message->subject('Keratin Product Order Form');
        $message->body(
            '<!doctype html>
            <html>
            <body>'.
            'Name: '.Input::get('name').'<br />'.
            'Email: '.Input::get('email').'<br />'.
            'Phone: '.Input::get('phone').'<br />'.     
            'Product Ordered:' .Input::get('product'). '<br />'.
            'Message: '.Input::get('message').'<br />'.
            '</body>
</html>'
        );

        $message->html(true);

    });

    if(Message::was_sent()){
        return Redirect::to_route('prods')->with('s-message','Your Order     Form has been successfully sent!')->with('show_order',true);
    }else{
        return Redirect::to_route('prods')->with('e-message','Sending Failed!')->with('show_order',true);
    }   

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974231/laravel-4-validation-nested-indexed-arrays/17980539#17980539

Answer (score 1):

`Input::get('product')` is the array of product names (`name="product[]" value="{{ $pp->name }}"`).

Instead of `'Product Ordered:' .Input::get('product')` you need

`'Products Ordered:' . implode(', ', Input::get('product'))`