# Laravel use translator in a translation string

Tags: php, laravel, translation, translate, language-translation

Would it be possible to use `trans()` in a lang file?

Eg: the line is `Please fill in your :attribute`
Let's say `:attribute` is password.

Would be possible to put `password` in the english lang file

and then use `wachtwoord` in the dutch lang file for `:attribute`?

Comment: Check this thread out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047116/laravel-validation-attributes-nice-names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use language specific attributes for this inside of your language validation file `lang/nl/validation.php` in the `attributes` array for example:

```
'attributes' => [
    'name' => 'naam'
    'password' => 'wachtwoord'
],
```

This will translate those attributes globably on all forms.

for a broader explanation check: [Laravel validation attributes "nice names"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047116/laravel-validation-attributes-nice-names)

Comment: How do I make a validator load said translations?

Comment: It should use them automaticly based on the locale you have set for your app