# How to use a translation of the label to display an error, instead of the label's name, when registering a user?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When registering a new user, I use a RegisterFormRequest from Laravel.

How can I use the label name translations to display correctly the error message ?

Here is my html code,

```
<div>
  <label for="password">
    {{ Lang::get('form.password') }} *
  </label>
  <input name="password" type="password" required>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="password_confirmation">
    {{ Lang::get('form.password.confirm') }} *
  </label>
  <input name="password_confirmation" type="password" class="form-control" required>
</div>
```

Here is what is displayed. Note that the input field's "password" is used as is, but not any translations.

[image]

Comment: Do you have file `resources\lang\en\validation.php` ? or you have folder other than `en` ?

Comment: I do have this folder, and others. However, no validation.php file. Are you implying that validation.php is the standard file where Laravel fetches translations automatically, for each input ?

Comment: Yes! it is the default one if you are trying to fetch the content of $erros variable, which it has been filled via `request`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in the Http\Controllers\YourController.php

```
public function postRegister(RegisterFormRequest $request)
{
    $validator = $this->registrar->validator($request->all());

    $validator = $validator->setAttributeNames( [
        'password' => 'My Password Name'
    ] );
```

will do the trick.

---

As @ali as implied, it might be better to put these values into your request class (it is where you can put the specific rules, so why not the specific label translation?).

> in the Http\Controllers\YourController.php

```
public function postRegister(RegisterFormRequest $request)
{
    $validator = $this->registrar->validator($request->all());

    $validator = $validator->setAttributeNames( $request->messages() );
```

> in the Http\Requests\RegisterFormRequest.php

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'password'        => Lang::get('form.password'),
```

[Laravel validation attributes "nice names"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047116/laravel-validation-attributes-nice-names)

And (as @mohamed-kawsara mentionned) in

> resources/lang/de/validation.php

```
return [

...

"confirmed"            => "The :attribute confirmation does not match.",

...
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is custom message in you request class.

Write this function in your request class.

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'password.required' => 'YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE FOR PASSWORD REQUIREMENT'
    ];
}
```