# laravel form validation variable text

Tags: laravel

How can I change the value used in the error feedback, lets say I have this rule:

```
$rules = array(
    'valid_country_code'                   => 'required',
);
```

But instead of 'valid_country_code' I want the user to see 'country' in the error message. The message at the moment.

> valid_country_code is required.

what I want

> country is required.

But I dont want to change the name in the form when posting because I want to bind the form to a model.

Comment: it has all been said in various questions on stack overflow... for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047116/laravel-validation-attributes-nice-names

Answer (score 0):

You may pass the custom messages as the third argument to the `Validator::make` method:

```
$rules = array(
    'valid_country_code' => 'required',
);

$messages = [
    'valid_country_code.required' => 'country is required.',
];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```