# How to localizite fields name in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

For example I have validation of HTML form:

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            "code" => "required|string|size:10"]);
```

If I get error it look as:

```
The code field is required.
```

Wrere `code` is name of field.

How can I translate(localize) this?

Comment: This is solution: `http://stackoverflow.com/a/34880398/6600504`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass 3rd argument in make method like this:

```
$rules = [
    "code" => "required|string|size:10",
];

$messages = [
    'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

> See more about [Custom Validation Error Messages](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-error-messages)

Hop this helps!