# Laravel language on Auth validation error

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.3

I would like to use the laravel default functionality to show the error, but in another language.
**I don't need a "nice name", but a translation for the **:attribute** value in lang files.
Right now if I just use:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{{ trans('generic.phone') }}" name="phone" value="{{ old('phone') }}">
@if ($errors->has('phone'))
<span class="help-block">
    <strong>{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</strong>
</span>
@endif
```

it works perfectly, because the **:attribute** takes the field **phone**, and in the validation language I have:

```
'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
```

But how to manage **phone** field with a language file?

**Do I must have to write a custom error for each field?** Please tell me I don't.

> The following function is just a **wrong example** to let you understand what
>   I'm trying to do

```
@if ($errors->has('phone'))
    <strong>{{ $errors->first(trans('generic.phone')) }}</strong>
@endif
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel validation attributes "nice names"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047116/laravel-validation-attributes-nice-names)

Comment: Now you have `auth.php` file only in `en` directory, create other locale directories, Ex: `es`, `fr`. And paste all files there: `auth.php`, `passwords.php`... You can take translated files from here: [https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang](https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang)

Comment: @zgabievi I know that, but I need to translate the **:attribute** too and this is set in the controller/view not in lang.

Comment: There is ** Custom Validation Attributes** array in `validation.php` file. I think you are looking for that one.

Comment: @Ken you're right, it's a duplicate, I saw the question you said. The problem it's the Laravel version, and that he posted a misleading question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Really simple!**
Just add attributes in the language file!
In my case, for `lang/it/validation.php`

I just set:

```
'attributes' => [
    'phone' => 'telefono',
],
```

while all remain the same for the sentences

```
'required' => 'Il campo :attribute &grave; obbligatorio.',
```