# Stop Laravel Validation replacing underscores with a space in :attribute placeholder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using a [Validator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#manually-creating-validators) to validate request parameters and return helpful messages to the users of a public API. If the validator fails I return a view:

```
if( $validator->fails() ){
    $data = ['errors' => $validator->errors()->messages() ];
    return response()->view('errors.412', $data, 412)
                    ->header("HTTP/1.0 412 Precondition Failed", null);
} else {
    ...
}
```

The view...

```
<ul>
    @foreach( $errors as $field )
        @foreach( $field as $error )
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Because these messages are to be consumed by developers I want them to be technical and specific. Therefore it's really annoying that Laravel automatically strips the space from my parameter keys.

For the message:

`'The :attribute field is required.'`

Laravel returns:

> The vehicle name field is required.

...but I want the more accurate:

> The vehicle_name field is required.

The only fix I have found is to add the following lines to `/resources/lang/en/validation.php`:

```
'attributes' => [
    'vehicle_name' => 'vehicle_name'
],
```

But that just feels backwards that I would have to provide a bunch of identical key-pair values in a language translation file just to instruct the framework to undo an unwanted behaviour.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Look into this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20633014/3226121

Comment: This could also help [api docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.html#method___construct)

`Validator::make($request->all(), [ rules ...], [ messages ... ], [ custom attributes])`

Custom attributes is what you want

It is repetitive, but that's one way you can do it...

Comment: [Validator __construct](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L197)

Comment: `$rules = [
      'access_key1' => 'nullable|string|max:200',
      'access_key2' => 'numeric',
      'access_key3' => 'array',
    ];

    $keys = array_keys($rules);

    $customAttributes = array_combine($keys, $keys);

    Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, [], $customAttributes);`

Answer (score 3):

This was the cleanest way for me:

```
  $rules = [
    'access_key1' => 'nullable|string|max:200',       
    'access_key2' => 'numeric',       
    'access_key3' => 'array',     
  ];      

  $keys = array_keys($rules);      
  $customAttributes = array_combine($keys, $keys);      
  Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, [], $customAttributes);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer came via a comment on a feature request that I posted on laravel/internals GitHub repo https://github.com/laravel/internals

I had gone down a wrong path in using a *view* to display the errors. For technical users, returning the errors in JSON is the most appropriate format and in that context the specific keys of the parameter are visible:

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "vehicle_name": [
            "The vehicle name field is required"
        ]
    }
}
```

So I changed my code to return JSON in the case of validation failure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own messages for every rule:

```
    $data = $request->all();

    $messages= [
                'access_key.required'      => 'access_key is required, I'm technical x)',
                'access_key.max'           => 'Yooo! calm down! you exceded max characters limit'

            ];

    $rules = [
                'access_key'      => 'required|max:255',
            ];

    return Validator::make($data,$rules, $messages);
```

If you don't provide a message for some rule it will use default message (replacing your underscores).

So this way is like add a single flag to every rule but giving you the opportunity to rewrite the whole message and ommit whatever field you don't want to provide a specific message.

Comment: Given that I don't mind the default message, do you think re-supplying the whole message for each parameter makes for better code than entries in the attributes array of the language file?

Comment: You can combine them, just replace the message with `trans('file.array.message')` and write your message in every language file. Maybe I miss something but I think this would be the way.